# Alarm goes off too early in android

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I want to set alarm for a specific time, I tried the code below. The problem is, most of the time alarm goes off within 10 seconds. I tried getting value of `time` in a toast and that seems to be perfectly fine.

```
Calendar cur_cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cur_cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());//set the current time and date for this calendar

Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, cur_cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 54);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.DATE, cur_cal.get(Calendar.DATE));
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, cur_cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));

long futureInMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + delay;
long time = cal.getTimeInMillis()-(System.currentTimeMillis());

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, time, (1000*60*60*24) , pendingIntent);

Toast.makeText(context, "alarm set for" + time, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

I also tried,

```
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, time, pendingIntent);
```

also,

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 24*60*60*1000, pendingIntent);
```

and,

```
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Comment: What do you exactly mean by goes off?

Comment: @Rahulrr2602 it firer, or you can say it sends out notification.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question("I want to set alarm for a specific time"), you want the alarm to sound at--lets say 10 AM tomorrow. However, your code seems to be in contradiction to this statement, because you are calculating a time difference:

`long time = cal.getTimeInMillis()-(System.currentTimeMillis());`

You may also be experiencing an issue the `AlarmManager` has by with the `setRepeating()` method. The Android documentation says:

> Note: as of API 19, all repeating alarms are inexact. If your
>   application needs precise delivery times then it must use one-time
>   exact alarms, rescheduling each time as described above. Legacy
>   applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will
>   continue to have all of their alarms, including repeating alarms,
>   treated as exact.

So, if you do want to set an alarm for a specific time (and not a time difference) just try this:

`long time = cal.getTimeInMillis();`

You might also consider changing to the `setExact()` method and creating code to repeat as needed (there are examples on the Internet).

Link to Android documentation:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)

Comment: I tried `cal.getTimeInMillis()` but nothing no improvement.

Comment: I also tried setExact(). but the problem exists.

I wonder why is the alarm firing so early when the `time` is exactly how much I want the alarm to delay from current time.

Comment: In your updated post you show that you have "also tried" `alarmManager.set()` which is not the same as `alarmManager.setExact()`. Could please explain in a little more detail what you want to happen and exactly what is happening. I do not understand "I wonder why is the alarm firing so early" --what do you mean by "early" (seconds, minutes)?